# Right hand side not simplified even with symmetry

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Getting started with Coq and "Software Foundation" problems, I run into the following example:

```
Theorem plus_O_n : forall n : nat, 0 + n = n.
Proof.
  intros n. simpl. reflexivity.  Qed.
```

Which is proved just fine. When however, I try the right-hand side equation;

```
Theorem plus_n_O : forall n, n = n + 0.
Proof.
  intros n. simpl. (* Doesn't do anything! *)
```

And this in fact, is one of the excercises in the book, why does `simpl` not work in that case. I was trying to be smart, so I reversed the equation using `symmetry`.

```
Theorem plus_n_O : forall n, n = n + 0.
Proof.
  intros n. simpl. symmetry. simpl. (* Doesn't do anything still!!! *)
```

But still no bueno. It's especially weird because `symmetry` works as expected and brings my goal to the same form as `plus_O_n`.

Comment: Look closer, `symmetry` won't get you the same goal than before. Then look at how `plus` is defined, then you will see that indeed your goal cannot be simplified, you need to perform additional steps.

Comment: Could it be that the commutative property is not defined yet for my addition? Looks like `0+n` is treated different that `n+0`

Comment: Indeed `0+n` is treated different than `n+0`. "+" is a function, you can see its "rules" issuing `Print plus`. Then, you should find your answer in SF.

Comment: you'd better walk it through from the beginning of of nat's definition. it helps you understand algebra is nothing but logical consequences of a bunch of rules. to finish your proof, you need to use a specific proof technique.

Comment: Try to do the job of the evaluator and compute `plus 0 n` manually, then do `plus n 0`. What's the difference?